# Get displayed image index

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have an array of pictures in such format:

```
 [#<BookPhotoUploader:0x00000042103ec0
 @file=
  #<CarrierWave::SanitizedFile:0x000000421013e0
   @content_type=nil,
   @file=
    "/.../.../.../public/uploads/book/pictures/1/first.jpg",
   @original_filename=nil>,
 @model=
  #<Book:0x00000049fab1f0
   id: 1,
   ...
   pictures: ["first.jpg", "second.jpg"]>,
 @mounted_as=:pictures,
 @storage=
  #<CarrierWave::Storage::File:0x00000046803dw0
   @uploader=#<BookPhotoUploader:0x00000042103ec0 ...>>,
 @versions={}>,
...]
```

When I display a picture it looks like:

```
<img id="book_picture" src="/uploads/book/pictures/1/first.jpg" alt="First">
```

How do I find a particular picture index in the array if I'm trying to get info about a picture which is shown using jquery?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? You show some images from the array and want to save to them some information about the index the images have in the array? You may use e.g. `each_with_index` to loop through all images together with their index and store the index in a `data` attribute of the image tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I add a picture index attribute to my img tag:

```
<img id="book_picture" index = 1 src="/uploads/book/pictures/1/first.jpg" alt="First">
```